# Nutch and Solr in Eclipse in WINDOWS

Tags: eclipse, solr, nutch

I want to use nutch and solr integrated in eclipse and my os is windows. I want to use binary files and dependencies with maven then develop code in eclipse. Is there any *clear* tutorial for doing this?

I have tried RunNutchInEclipse guide but it is so nasty! Any useful links or advices are welcome.

Thnx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to follow RunNutchInEclipse guide. There are no other guides as far as I know. Even I tried initially to run on windows and I gave up later and started using on Ubuntu/Mac. There will be many issues which you will see even if you follow the guide. There is some problem with hadoop on windows. The hadoop version which comes with Nutch 1.3+ does not work on windows. So we need to change hadoop version to some older version. Or we should use Nutch 1.2. I remember seeing a tutorial in youtube. See if that helps. But that said it is definitely easier to use Nutch on Unix flavors.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i wonder is there any other easy integrated crawler for solr other than nutch?